# Javascript can't get text inputed by Sahi in an <input type="text">

Tags: php, bdd, behat, sahi, mink

TL;DR : In a Behat+Mink  (`@javascript` w/ Sahi) scenario, Sahi enter some text in an `<input>`, and the Javascript in the page isn't able to get what was entered by Sahi

## UPDATE:

Solution : downloading the last version of Sahi fixed the problem. Whatever the bug was, it has been corrected.

## Context

I'm building a little demo website, to show my team what Behat+Mink can do. There's a few pages, where one can input the size of a square and get the perimeter of this square.
One page is using plain old POST method, another page is using Javascript to calculate the perimeter

Url of the "JS page" : http://behatdemo.widop.com/js-square

To show my team that testing javascript is possible, I'm using Sahi as Mink driver, however it doesn't seems to work. I wrote a scenario where a user input `6` as the square side length, and get `24` as perimeter ([link to file on github] (https://github.com/clemherreman/behatdemo/blob/master/features/js_square.feature#L7))

```
@javascript
Scenario: Inputting a valid side size
Given I am on "/js-square"
When I fill in "side" with "6"
And I press "Calculate"
And I wait for the result to appear
And I wait a little
Then I should see "Perimeter (using js): 24 cm"
```

*Note: `And I wait a little` is a debug steps that waits 10 seconds, to be able to look at what is displayed on the Sahi firefox window*

## Problem

It seems that the snippet of javascript that calculate the perimeter isn't able to get the `6` inputed by Sahi. Here is the code ([link to file on github] (https://github.com/clemherreman/behatdemo/blob/master/website/views/js-square.twig#L27))

Instead of having `"Perimeter (using js): 24 cm"`, I get a `"Perimeter (using js): Error cm"`.

```
(function($) {
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // #side is a <input type="text"> tag, where user input a square side length
    var side = parseFloat(jQuery('#side').val()) || NaN;
    var perimeter = side*4.0 || 'Error';
    $('#sidebar').text('Perimeter (using js): '+perimeter+ ' cm');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

## Debug/Ideas

After some investigation, it turns out that `jQuery('#side').val()`returns an empty string, which is why I get a "Error" displayed, instead of the perimeter. 
**It seems that Javascript isn't able to get what was inputed by Sahi during the Scenario**.

I'm pretty stuck on this one, I feel like I'm missing something.

**Links** :

- Github project (with `*.features`): https://github.com/clemherreman/behatdemo
- Live website: http://behatdemo.widop.com/js-square

**Versions**:

- Behat: 2.1.2
- Mink: 1.1.1
- Sahi: 3.5
- PHP: 5.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your error, everythig went fine on my Behat/Mink/Sahi setup : 
http://screencast.com/t/2rTHo7jj

Scenario passed

I'm using **Sahi 3.5** with **Behat 2.1.2** and **Mink 1.1.1** on OSX With latest version of **Chrome** & PHP **5.3.8-ZS5.5.0**

Try running your test under Chrome with :

```
default:
  context:
    parameters:
      base_url: YOURBASEURL
      browser: chrome
```

Comment: Holy cow, thank you for taking the time to do that. I see you are using OS X, like me. Do you think my bug might come from a version difference between you and me ? Can you list vour version number for Behat, Mink, PHP, Sahi, even Firefox ? Ty again =)

Comment: I don't want to impose on you kindness, but if you run the Scenario using firefox, does it still work ? If so (or even if not), tell me what version of Firefox you have (if you have any). I'd really like to be able to reproduce this bug.

Comment: Using Firefox 8, and it's working too :). No idea why it's not in your case. :O

Comment: Problem is that me neither. I'll investigate and post on this question if I found out why it isn't working. Ty for you time =)

Comment: Updating to last version of Sahi fixed it, see my question.